# Настройка denyCurrentBranch и глюки с ней

Tags: git, git-push

Поставил опцию git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore

1. Делаю изменение у себя на локалке.
2. Заливаю со своего пк на сервер в бранч master напрямую http://clip2net.com/s/j885ch
3. Коммиты между локалкой и сервером совпадают 2ddb99ce287d56d3d3ace177da0380ac8ccbdea2, если повторно делаю push, то пишет, все ок http://clip2net.com/s/j887Ma
4. Но почему-то на сервере пишет http://clip2net.com/s/j8897l , что файл изменен, хотя коммит прошел.

Comment: Взяли бы дифом и посмотрели, что там на сервере не так.

А Вы на сервере тоже этот файл меняли?

Comment: На сервере файл не менял. В тот то и дело.

Comment: diff смотрели? (git diff на сервере). Он покажет, что там не так в файле. Возможно, что там переводы строк.


Но не думайте, что если Вы запушили с своей машины изменения, то они должны поменять на сервере в "рабочем каталоге".

Comment: До, оно видит изменения которые я сделал. Но почему оно пишет статус у файла modified. Выходит что мне еще один коммит надо делать но уже на сервере, чтобы бранч был чистый? Я именно этого не пойму: На локалке когда пушу на сервер бранч чист, а на сервере бранч modified html_block.xml. Может опция есть спец у push, чтобы пушило точь в точь.

Comment: Думаю, что Вы не до конца понимаете разницу между рабочей копией и репозиторием. У Вас файл измененный в рабочей копии на сервере. Вообще-то не очень красиво лазить в файлы на сервере. Но если нужно - делайте только pull. Я могу объяснить, почему Вы так наблюдаете, но это затянется на насколько тысяч слов. Я могу порекомедовать только перечитать статьи по git.

Comment: Дело в том, что файл html_block.xml, который я напрямую заливаю в бранч master при опции denyCurrentBranch ignore, на сервере файл html_block.xml остается старым, а в git status появляется modified html_block.xml. И в итоге чтобы мне сделать точную копию репозитория мне нужно сделать git reset --hard "Последний коммит, который я сделал на локалке у себя" и тогда на сервере будет все так же. Я не могу понять, почему когда я делаю push с локалки на сервер, то на сервере в итоге не точная копия файла, а какие-то статусы modified html_block.xml, после чего мне приходится делать git reset --hard.

Comment: Потому что пуш на сервер не изменяет рабочую копию на сервере.

Comment: Почему тогда, если бы я сделал push в branch develop и потом переключился, то бранч develop был бы идентичен. Выходит, что это особенность опции receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore. Если делать push в тек. активный бранч, то push ведет себя таким образом? Может, опции к нему нужно написать push "-[a-z]"?

Answer (score 1):

суть непонимания автором вопроса происходящего отражена в вопросах в комментариях:

> Я не могу понять, почему когда я делаю push с локалки на сервер, то на сервере в итоге не точная копия файла, а какие-то статусы modified html_block.xml, после чего мне приходится делать git reset

ответ KoVadim-а: Потому что пуш на сервер **не изменяет** рабочую копию на сервере

> Почему тогда, если бы я сделал push в branch develop и потом переключился, то бранч develop был бы идентичен

потому что «переключение» (`checkout`) **изменяет** рабочую копию файлов (так же, как и «сброс» (`reset`) выше).

---

вообще правильным ответом можно считать совет: делайте `push` только в *bare-репозиторий*; не делайте `push` в репозиторий, возле которого развёрнута рабочая копия файлов: они при этом **не изменятся**.

Comment: Можно ещё делать `push` в другую ветку, и потом мержить в текущую.